# tymondesigns/jwt-auth: how create an expired token?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm using V1 of https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

I need to create an expired token, to test the `TokenExpiredException` in my code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid'], 401);
            } elseif ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired'], 401);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorization Token not found'], 401);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

I cannot do it:

```
public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $password = '123456';
        $user = new User([
            'email' => 'info@example.com',
            'password' => Hash::make($password),
        ]);
        $user->save();
    }

public function testExpiredToken()
{
    $user = User::first();
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user, ['exp'=> 123456]);

   $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        ])->get(Route('test_data_read_closed'));
        $response->assertStatus(401);
}
```

But I get 200 from my test (token accepted, I got answer from my route) and not 401.

How can I create an expired token? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to figure out why it was still responding with a 200 success code when an expired JWT is sent (for testing purposes). It turns out that the JWT package caches the claims in the `\Tymon\JWTAuth\Factory` instance. To fix it, you just have to clear the claims after the JWT is generated and before it's sent to a controller:

```
\Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::getPayloadFactory()->emptyClaims();
```

Otherwise, it thinks it's the same request and will re-use already built `\Tymon\JWTAuth\Claims\Claim` instances to decode another JWT. I will see about creating an issue on GitHub.